# Include an explanation of migrated questions in the Help Center

Tags: feature-request, migration, help-center

One user just asked [how they can request migration](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6958/how-to-request-a-migration) for a question, but they did not find an answer, even when they searched the Help Center. So, it's really nice to see that people are using it, but I think this essential part of a question's lifecycle is still missing.

The page about [closed questions](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions) does not even mention the concept of migration in passing, although a sentence would probably already suffice.

Ideally, there would be a separate article dedicated to this, maybe something like "What are migrated questions?"

Comment: Now I'm really curious, since this was downvoted—why would a help center page be *not* be a good idea?

Comment: People hate migrations or don't want to make that option visible?  Not sure.

Comment: Weird, why would anyone downvote this?